# unable to navigate in dashboard after checking credential in e2e testing

Tags: angular8, e2e-testing

I am new to e2e testing. I am writing test cases for angular login page its working in login but i am unable to navigate to homePage after checking login credential
I am getting this in console.

1. It will route to home page When username password is correct then go to home page

- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, app-homepage h1)

2. should  Login work when login is successful — he should redirect to default home page page

- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, app-homepage h1)

this is my spec file

```
import { LoginPage } from './login.po';
import { HomePage } from '../HomePgE2E/home.po';

describe('should  Login work', () => {
  let page: LoginPage;
  let homePage:HomePage;
  const wrongCredentias = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new LoginPage();
   homePage= new HomePage();
  });

  it('when user trying to login with wrong credentials he should stay on “login” page', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    page.fillCredentials(wrongCredentias);
    expect(page.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('Sign in to your account');
    expect(page.getErrorMessage()).toEqual('Email cannot be empty.');
  });

  it('when login is successful — he should redirect to default home page page ', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    page.fillCredentials();
    homePage.navigateTo();
    expect(homePage.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('welcome');
  });
});
```

And this welcome text coming from

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class HomePage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/home');
  }

   getPageTitleText() {
    return element(by.css('app-homepage h1')).getText();
  } 
}
```

Comment: I still stuck in this issue seriously looking for solution please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should work

```
import { LoginPage } from './login.po';
import { HomePage } from '../HomePgE2E/home.po';

describe('should  Login work', () => {
  let page: LoginPage;
  let homePage:HomePage;
  const wrongCredentias = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };

  beforeEach(async async () => {
   page = await new LoginPage();
   homePage=await new HomePage();
  });

  it('when user trying to login with wrong credentials he should stay on “login” page', async () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    await page.fillCredentials(wrongCredentias);
    expect(page.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('Sign in to your account');
    expect(page.getErrorMessage()).toEqual('Email cannot be empty.');
  });

  it('when login is successful — he should redirect to default home page page ', () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    await page.fillCredentials();
    await homePage.navigateTo();
    expect(homePage.getPageTitleText()).toEqual('welcome');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks Ganesh its works but i am getting chrome driver issue .

Comment: That you can resolve it by installing chrome specific version driver using webdirver-manager

    webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome <version_required>